# Corrupt Install message when Bluestacks run on different user

Tags: windows-10, user-accounts, bluestacks

I installed BlueStacks on the admin account recently, and have used it on that account only, until now. I tried to use it on another account, only to have it say "Installation is corrupt".

I uninstalled it and reinstalled in on that user account, and it worked fine. But now the admin account isn't working.

I reinstalled BlueStacks back on the admin account, but I still want all users to have access to Bluestacks. What are the options?

Comment: @1Fish_2Fish_RedFish_BlueFish I don't think that's the issue. The issue is that another user, even though they have access to Bluestacks itself, cannot run the program properly. If it was installed on another account, for example, admin is not able to run it. Good post though, got my upvote.

Comment: Well I was wondering that if doing it this way in your case, if that would actually emulate everything to start as the actual cached credential that you installed it with and you know it works from with it's account. If it's not an actual issue with you need to be a local administrator to run this software (or in your environment everyone is perhaps) then I was wondering if you actually used that solution, if that would emulate that same one user account's profile executing it from and it'd just work... It'd be an obvious workaround rather than a long-term solution, but maybe doable.

Comment: Here's the link again if you don't have it, but I went ahead and cleaned it up a bit as I said I would layout wise with the same content for the most part.  http://serverfault.com/questions/734320/allow-standard-user-to-run-program-as-local-admin-without-elevation-prompt/734360#734360 ... and if you think I should add as an answer here, I'll be happy to do that as well. I know the real solution would be for the software to just work regardless of who installs it. I'm reading around on that too and I see some start Virtual Box VMs in one post.. still looking though.